# Get records closest to hour 05:00 am. I have a hour and minute column and need to get records which are closest to 5am. Hard coding to 5am is also ok

Tags: sql, oracle

SAMPLE DATA:

```
order_id  location   departhour  departmin
121        boston     10          11
121        boston     14          00
```

from the above data i want to get the record which has departhour 10 as that is closest to 5am. hour and minute are number datatypes.

Comment: Post table description (what is that column's datatype?) and sample data, as well as desired result.

Comment: Looks like a serious design flaw.  Why are you keeping 'hour' and 'minute' as separate columns?  Most likely they should be a part of a single column of type DATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you posted how data look like, then something like this might help:

```
SQL> with test (order_id, location, departhour, departmin) as
  2    (select 121, 'Boston', 10, 11 from dual union all
  3     select 121, 'Boston', 14,  0 from dual union all
  4     select 200, 'London', 23, 55 from dual
  5    )
  6  select order_id, location, departhour, departmin
  7  from (select t.*,
  8          rank() over (order by abs(trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 5/24 -
  9                         to_date(lpad(t.departhour, 2, '0') ||
 10                                 lpad(t.departmin, 2, '0'), 'hh24mi'))
 11                      ) rnk
 12        from test t
 13       )
 14  where rnk = 1;

  ORDER_ID LOCATI DEPARTHOUR  DEPARTMIN
---------- ------ ---------- ----------
       121 Boston         10         11

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- sample data in lines #1 - 5
- subquery (lines #7 - 11) converts departhour and departmin values to a valid date; its day defaults to first of current month (01.07.2021), so I'm subtracting that day's 5th hour (01.07.2021 05:00) and "calculated" date from your table (and applying the `abs` function as time may be before or after 05:00 hours)
- ranking the difference (line #8) means that the result which is the *least* is to be returned as the closest to 05:00

---

You never said that e.g. `order_id` should also be considered (i.e. "give me row closest to 05:00 per each `order_id`) so I didn't pay attention to it either. If you should do it, then include partition clause into the `rank` function.

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot i tried this. Worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the follow table

```
create table sample_table
(
id number generated by default as identity,
date_sample date
);

insert into sample_table (date_sample) values (to_date('08/07/2021 06:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into sample_table (date_sample) values (to_date('08/07/2021 04:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into sample_table (date_sample) values (to_date('08/07/2021 03:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into sample_table (date_sample) values (to_date('08/07/2021 02:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into sample_table (date_sample) values (to_date('08/07/2021 01:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into sample_table (date_sample) values (to_date('08/07/2021 04:59:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
```

If you want the closest record before or after 5am, you can use the select below

```
select id,
       date_sample,
       abs(to_date('08/07/2021 05:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') -
           date_sample) result
  from sample_table
 order by result
 fetch first row only
```

If you want only before 5am, you can use this select:

```
select *
  from (select id,
               date_sample,
               to_date('08/07/2021 05:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') -
               date_sample result
          from sample_table)
 where result >= 0
 order by result
 fetch first row only
```

You can use the follow code to get the 5am of sysdate

```
trunc(sysdate) + interval '5' hour
```